# Spring MVC using tomcat, maven and intelliJ Error

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I know this question is asked several times, but none of the solutions could help me out.
Here's link to project [project file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1js4tHGX0VHWYH1JPhxnvRGMsqciUSSys?usp=sharing). 
Hoping anyone could help me out **JDK-11**

Error is class cast exception cannot figure out where specifically error lies and why? even referenced several sites still the error persist stack trace is attached for more details uploaded project to above mentioned link

**Tomcat LocalHost log**

```
17-Sep-2020 00:14:07.543 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet [dispatcher] as unavailable
17-Sep-2020 00:14:07.543 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/springMVC_war_exploded] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @2bc757; jakarta.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @478190fc)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1043)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:984)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4813)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5122)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)<br/>
```

**pom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springMVC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
<!--        Spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        Servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        maven-->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Tomcat config
[image: TomCat description file]

artifact[image]

Comment: Remove `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1` from the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. The Servlet API is supplied by Tomcat, so having that file is the webapps local classpath causes conflict. --- Don't know what you did to get it there, it wasn't added by Maven, as can be seen by the lack of the `Maven:` prefix. Don't know why you did it, given that it is already in your classpath as "provided".

Comment: @Andreas Error changes to
class not found exception:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Comment: @CrazyCoder corrected it but error still persist

Comment: **Tomcat 10** is for Servlet 5.0, which **is not backwards compatible**, given that all the Java types were moved from package `javax.servlet` to package `jakarta.servlet`. Don't use beta version of Tomcat 10, **use Tomcat 9**.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your advice. I didn't know that. I will let you know whether it's successful or not.

Comment: See [Migrating from 9.0.x to 10.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat 10 is for Servlet 5.0, which is **not backwards compatible** with earlier versions of the Servlet specification.

That is because all the Java types were moved from package `javax.servlet` to package `jakarta.servlet`.

Don't use Tomcat 10, use Tomcat 9.

If you want to upgrade to Tomcat 10 or later, see [Apache Tomcat® - Migration Guide - Tomcat 10.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html).

---

See [Spring Framework issue #25354](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25354) *(Support for Jakarta EE 9 (annotations and interfaces in jakarta.* namespace))* for status of Spring support for Servlet 5.0 / Tomcat 10.